# AngularJS jsonp success error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bing-maps

Hi I'm trying tu get BING MAPS API using Angularjs but I'm getting this error in console:

```
TypeError: $http.jsonp(...).success is not a function
```

Here is my controller

```
   .controller('bingMaps', ['$scope', '$http', MapController]);

    function MapController($scope, $http) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.mapsearch = function() {
            var url = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&key=MYKEY&o=json";
            $http.jsonp(url)
                .success(function(data){
                    console.log('success');
                })
                .error(function () {
                    console.log('error')
                });

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't using jQuery. There is no `success` method. The function returns a standard promise. It has a `then` method (which takes two arguments, the success callback and the error callback).

See [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) for examples.

Comment: Also, `$http.jsonp` is not really function in AngularJS' `$http` service.

Comment: Is there any chance to use get method? Now it's has been blocked by CORS

Comment: @EdinPuzic — If you want to use `get` then you need to have permission from the server you are making the request to. (If you want to use JSONP then you also need that permission, it is just expressed in the form of the data being sent in JSONP rather than using the more explicit and flexible CORS approach).

Answer (score 5):

Angular v1.6 removed `success` and `error` methods from JSONP:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues in your Bing Maps REST URL:

- There is no callback parameter. There is a jsonp parameter.
- You haven't provided a query to search for, so there will be an error with the request.

Here is a modified version of your query:

http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK&key=MYKEY&o=json&q=[your search query]

I recommend taking a look at the best practices for Bing Maps:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn894107.aspx

There is also a useful blog post on how to use the Bing Maps REST services with different JavaScript frameworks here:

https://blogs.bing.com/maps/2015/03/05/accessing-the-bing-maps-rest-services-from-various-javascript-frameworks/